# Server hung due to high CPU utilization

Tags: .net, windows, powershell, vmware

Server is in hung state. Its not responding to any key strokes. Is there any way to see which process has been utilising high CPU usage?

Comment: Press Ctrl + Alt + Delete and open task manager :)

Comment: `pslist`, `tasklist`, `tlist`, `process explorer`, `wpr`, `perfmon`, ... the list is kind of endless

Comment: @AkashKC you can open taks manager with ctrl + shift + esc easier :)

Comment: Its not responding to any key strokes.

Comment: You can execute pslist from another computer `pslist \\hungcomputer -s -t`

Answer (score 0):

You can get the highest CPU utilizing process with Powershell this way:

```
Get-Process | Sort-Object CPU -Descending | Select -First 1
```

Comment: I cant even login to the server, Tried to run remoting script using get-wmiobject . But no luck as the server is not responding to any key strokes

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you can't check the CPU utilization for the past unless the application itself would have made a Event log entry by itself.

Answer (score 0):

If it's so busy that it won't even respond to key strokes, then it's time to pull the power.  I'd then setup a perfmon trace for process/%ProcessorTime and leave it running for a few days.  If the issue occurs again, you'll at least have some historic info.